# regex to exclude few files but include rest

Tags: regex

I have multilevel directory structure and I want to list all (png,jpeg files), except files, say, sam.png, pam.jpeg etc from any directory

Ultimately, I want to list all files as

```
a/b/c/d*.jpg (inlude all jpg, but I want to exclude sam.png from a/b/c/d directory)

a/b/c/d*.jpeg

a/b/c/d*.png

a/e/f/k/h/*.png
```

...and so on

How do I do that?

Comment: why do you want regex for this, what language is this for?

Comment: This isn't really something I'd use regex for, have an array with the fielnames that you want to ignore, and loop through all of the files in the directories, if the filename is in the ignore array, don't show it.

Comment: There are 6000 files in those directories and sub directories so I need to use wild card. after adding wild card the list shrinks to 100, which I can live with. Ultimately I need to tell web server (Apache) to serve these pages.

Comment: Are you using a some programming language OR bash scripting?

Answer (score 3):

Use following `regex` -

```
.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png)$(?<!sam.png|pam.jpeg)
```

This uses [negative look behind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

Comment: thanks, so if do ls | egrep '*.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png)$(?<!sam.png|pam.jpeg)' that should show me all the files except sam.png or pam.jpeg? didn't work that way :-( The first part of egrep worked egrep '*.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png)'

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completly sure of the context of you problem.

However you can use `find .` to list and files under a directory (recursive).

Use `egrep` to filter the result with a regexp.

And then use `egrep -v` to filter in a negative way (if it doesn't match stays).

So I guess something like this might do the job:

```
find . | egrep "*.(jpg|png)$" | egrep -v "*.(sam.png)"
```

Comment: I guess I didn't state the problem correctly..The sam.jpg files don't exist in the file system. So you will not find them. They exist somewhere else. However in the ultimate list, I want to able to specify to include all png files but not sam.png so the line should look like a/b/c/d/(regex to include all png but sam.png) each and every line will state that include all png but exclude sam.png

Comment: Ok they don't exist in the file system, then just replace "find ." for the thing that returns what you need to filter. If you really need it to be done in just one regexp (because you are using it in some specific system) be ware that stuf like: ".(jpg|png)$(?<!sam.png|pam.jpeg)" will only work if the RegExp parser used by the program uses lookbehind. The kind of string validation you want cannot be done in a single iteration. Hope it helped ;)